# Segmentation Fault 11 while trying to run compiled C++ code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I am doing an assignment (.csv-parser) for uni. While trying to run the code after compilation it returns a SegFault 11.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

string line;
string buffer;

vector<vector<string> > database;
vector<string> dataset;

//bool start = true;

ifstream denkmaeler;
denkmaeler.open(argv[1]);
ifstream denkmal;
denkmal.open(argv[1]);

int semic = 1;
//int semic2 = 1;
int zaehler = 0;

if (denkmal.is_open()){
    (getline(denkmal, buffer));

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++ ){
        if(buffer[i] == ';'){
            semic++;}

    }
}

denkmal.close();

if(denkmaeler.is_open()) {
    //if (counter < 1) {
    while (getline(denkmaeler, buffer));
    if (line.back() == *argv[2]) {
        line += argv[2];
        stringstream ss(line);
        while (getline(ss, line, *argv[2])) {
            dataset.push_back(line);
            database.push_back(dataset);
            dataset.clear();

        }
    }


}

for (int x=0, y=semic; x < semic; y=database.size(), x++, y++){
    if (x > semic){
        x=0;
        cout << '\n' << "-------------------------------" << '\n' << endl;

    }
    if (database[y][0].length() == 0){
        database[y][0] = "not available";
    }

    cout << database[x][0] << " : "  << database[y][0] << endl;
}
}
```

If someone would be able to point out my mistake I would be very thankful. I read some posts pointing out that the problem could be an array but I am not sure how that could be.

Comment: Does it segfault during compilation, or during execution? If it's the former, then there's a problem with your compiler.

Comment: If your compiler is crashing, it's important to share exactly which compiler you are using, which version you are using and what compilation flags you are using.

Comment: It is during compiling but it also won't compile under Windows 10. Using GCC which came with Xcode.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Only using -o to name the executable.

Comment: The most obvious error is you're missing `using namespace std;` after the includes, since you're trying to use `string` etc. undecorated. If that's not it, can you show us the errors you're getting on Windows please? If GCC is crashing on invalid code that's a less serious error than crashing on valid. (And if it's the XCode tools it's probably actually LLVM not GCC I think.)

Comment: @MaxLatz Which version of gcc exactly?

Comment: @Rup it seems like it didn't copy it. I got using namespace std; in my code. But thank you. 

It doesn't give any errors on windows, it just does not compile.

Comment: ? If it's failing to compile there should be compiler errors?

Comment: @MaxLatz I simply get a compiler error here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5032a91b2844a5ae No compiler segfault. Maybe your compiler installation is screwed.

Comment: @Rup Ok, but the core dump is obviously drawn from `a.out` not the compiler (as the OP insists to claim). The question should be clarifed regarding this, and probably show some debugging efforts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ D'oh, yes, you're right.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Got it to compile. Now it is behaving exactly like the given examples by Rup. Just clarified the question.

Comment: @MaxLatz So the next step is to run your program in your debugger and investigate about the exact point of error stepping through line by line as mentioned. You shouldn't expect anyone volunteering here to do this work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For segmentation error, it is best to use a debugging tool which can exactly show you where the error is (which line)!

I am using gdb, i recommend you to google it